# Most efficient way to make a 9x9 entry grid in python using Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, sudoku

I want to make a 9x9 grid with entries because I want to make a sudoku solver but couldn't find an efficient way. I wanted to do it like this but don't think this is the best way.

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()



a1 = Entry(main)
a2 = Entry(main)
a3 = Entry(main)


a1.place(x=0, y=0, width=40)
a2.place(x=40, y=0, width = 40)
a3.place(x=80, y=0, width = 40)


main.mainloop()
```

Comment: What about using a for loop?

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 nested for loops, saving the Entry widgets in a list so you can access them later.

```
from tkinter import *

main = Tk()

entries = []
for a in range(0, 120, 40):
    for b in range(0, 120, 40):
        temp = Entry(main)
        temp.place(x=a, y=b, width=40, height=40)
        entries.append(temp)

main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with a custom class, and a dictionnary to store your boxes data; saved this as test.py, see picture of results[image: sample image]

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()


class Entry(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, master, x, y):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, master)

        self.data = tk.IntVar()
        self.textvariable = self.data
        self.grid(column=x, row=y)
        self.config(width=2)
        self.data.trace('w', self.edit_entry)

    def edit_entry(self, *args):
        self.data.set(self.get())

boxes = {}

box_name = 1
for x in range(9):
    for y in range(9):
        boxes[box_name] = Entry(root, y, x)
        box_name += 1

def print_grid():
    box_name = 1
    for x in range(9):
        for y in range(9):
            print(boxes[box_name].get(), end=',')
            box_name += 1
        print('')
```

Comment: I made a few edits... messed up with my code while posting.. from a python interpreter, just calling test.boxes[index].get() would give you that box value

Comment: You would also need to make this standalone using a mainloop, I just wanted to make a quick sample for you to work from.